# Javascript Not Hitting Checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to check for checkboxes that are checked, and print some labels from those check boxes. I am having a hell of a time actually getting it to work though. My JavaScript functions look like this:

```
function buildPrintList() {
    var frmMain = document.frmMain;
    var elPrintList = frmMain.printlist;
    var strTemp = '';
    var i = 0;

    // Put together a list of serials to delete.
    for (i = 0; i < frmMain.elements.length; i++) {

        if (frmMain.elements[i].type == 'checkbox' && frmMain.elements[i].name != 'activeonly') {

            if (frmMain.elements[i].checked)

            strTemp = strTemp + frmMain.elements[i].name + ',';
        }
    }

    // Clean up the list.
    if (strTemp.length > 0) strTemp = strTemp.substr(0, strTemp.length - 1);

    // Save the delete list to a element.
    elPrintList.value = strTemp;
}

function printLocationLabels() {
    var frmMain = document.frmMain;
    var elPrintList = frmMain.printlist;
    var elLabelSize = frmMain.labelsize;
    var strLabelSize = '';
    var strURL = '';
    var strTemp = '';
    var xmlHTTP2 = getXMLHTTPObject();

    // Jump out with an error if the object can't be created.
    if (xmlHTTP2 == null) {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return;
    }

    // Figure out which printer is selected.
    for (i = 0; i < elLabelSize.length; i++) {
        if (elLabelSize[i].checked) strLabelSize = elLabelSize[i].value;
    }

    // Create the URL.
    //strURL = './processors/printLocationLabels.asp?printlist=' + escape(elPrintList.value) + '&labelsize=' + escape(strLabelSize) + '&id=' + Math.random();
    strURL = './processors/printLocationLabels.asp?printlist=' + escape(elPrintList.value) + '&labelsize=' + escape(strLabelSize) + '&id=' + Math.random();

    xmlHTTP2.onreadystatechange = responseTextErrorCheck;
    xmlHTTP2.open("GET", strURL, true);
    xmlHTTP2.send(null);

}
```

My checkboxes are set up like this(The 1 in the name feild will increment if there are two of them):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="123<~>1" style="cursor:hand;" class=bodyText" onclick="buildPrintList();">
```

and the other like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="activeonly" value="1" checked class="bodyText">
```

My problem is that this part of my buildPrintList function is not being hit...

```
// Put together a list of serials to delete.
for (i = 0; i < frmMain.elements.length; i++) {
    if (frmMain.elements[i].type == 'checkbox' && frmMain.elements[i].name != 'activeonly') {
        if (frmMain.elements[i].checked) alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!" + strTemp);
        strTemp = strTemp + frmMain.elements[i].name + ',';
    }
}
```

I put a alert to say hello, show me the string you have built so far... and it never fires... Any idea why?

I changed things around, I made it fire an alert for each element on the page, and type and name etc....

This is what I changed....

```
for (i=0; i<frmMain.elements.length; i++){
        alert(frmMain.elements[i].type + " " +  
        frmMain.elements[i].name + " " + frmMain.elements[i].checked);  
}
```

This is what I get...

text - filter - false
selectone - classes - undefined
checkbox - activeonly - true
text - location - false
button - doit - false
hidden - action - false
hidden - index - false
hidden - classs - false
hidden - printlist - false
hidden - labelsize - false

```
        <input type="hidden" name="classs" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="printlist" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="labelsize" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="locations" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">
```

So now I am really confused because it does not even consider those other elements as checkboxs... These hidden variables will not overwrite a already defined type would it?

Another thing worth mentioning is that I am calling a separate page to build and populate the table... It is quite big, but I dont want to miss anything... This is where the checkbox's are being created though, which may explain why it is not showing up on the frmMain.elements....

```
strTemp = "<table width='100%' align='center' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0' border='0'>"
    strTemp = strTemp & "<tr>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='left' valign='bottom' nowrap colspan='7' class='bodyText'>"
            strTemp = strTemp & "<table width='65%' align='left' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0' border='0' style='border: 1px solid orangered;'>"
                strTemp = strTemp & "<tr>"
                    strTemp = strTemp & "<td width='5%' align='right' valign='middle' nowrap class='bodyText6'><span style='font-weight: bold; color: red;'>Note:</span></td>"
                    strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='left' valign='middle' nowrap class='bodyText6'> - Click in a cell to edit it's contents.</td>"
                strTemp = strTemp & "</tr>"
            strTemp = strTemp & "</table>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "</td>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='right' valign='bottom' colspan='2' nowrap class='bodyText'>"
            strTemp = strTemp & "<input type='button' name='locationssetup' value='Refresh Table' style='font-size: 8; cursor: hand;' class='bodyText' onMouseOver='this.style.color=""orangered"";' onMouseOut='this.style.color=""black"";' onClick='getLocationsTable();'></input>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "</td>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='right' valign='bottom' colspan='2' nowrap class='bodyText6'>"
            strTemp = strTemp & "<input type='radio' name='labelsize' value='2x3' style='cursor:hand;'>2x3 Labels</input><br><input type='radio' name='labelsize' value='4x6' checked style='cursor:hand;'>4x6 Labels</input><br>"
            strTemp = strTemp & "<input type='button' name='printlabels' value='Print Labels' style='cursor:hand;' class='bodyText6' onMouseOver='this.style.color=""orangered"";' onMouseOut='this.style.color=""black"";' onClick='if (!confirm(""Do you have the correct size labels in the printer?"")) return false; if (document.frmMain.printlist.value.length == 0) {alert(""No Locations Selected!""); return false;}  else {printLocationLabels();}'></input>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "</td>"

    strTemp = strTemp & "</tr>"
    strTemp = strTemp & "<tr style='background-color: darkorange; font-weight: bold;'>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='left' valign='bottom' nowrap class='bodyTextTL'>Location</td>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='center' valign='bottom' nowrap class='bodyTextTL'>Shelf</td>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='center' valign='bottom' nowrap class='bodyTextTL'>Description</td>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='center' valign='bottom' nowrap class='bodyTextTL'>Depth</td>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='center' valign='bottom' nowrap class='bodyTextTL'>Status</td>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='center' valign='bottom' nowrap class='bodyTextTL'>Class <span style='font-size:10;'>(class description)</span></td>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='center' valign='bottom' nowrap class='bodyTextTL'>Crossdock</td>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='center' valign='bottom' nowrap class='bodyTextTL'>Last<br>Cycle Count</td>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='center' valign='bottom' nowrap class='bodyTextTL'>CC<br>Priority<br><span style='font-size:8px;'>(1 - 10)</span></td>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='center' valign='bottom' nowrap class='bodyTextTL'>Active</td>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='center' valign='bottom' nowrap class='bodyTextTLR'>Print<br>Label</td>"
    strTemp = strTemp & "</tr>"

    If rsTemp.EOF Then

        strTemp = strTemp & "<tr height='35'>"
            strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='center' valign='middle' colspan='11' nowrap style='font-weight: bold;'class='bodyTextTLR'>No Data Found</td>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "</tr>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "<tr>"
            strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='center' valign='middle' nowrap colspan='11' style='font-weight: bold;' class='bodyTextT'>&nbsp</td>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "</tr>"

    Else

        Do While Not rsTemp.EOF
            strActive = "Active"
            If rsTemp("active") = 0 Then
                strActive = "Dormant"
            End If
            strTemp = strTemp & "<tr>"
                strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='left' valign='middle' nowrap class='bodyTextTL'>" & Trim(rsTemp("location")) & "&nbsp</td>"
                strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='left' valign='middle' nowrap style='cursor:hand;' class='bodyTextTL' onMouseOver='this.style.color=""red"";' onMouseOut='this.style.color=""black"";' onClick='updateLocationsTable(""" & rsTemp("location") & """,""" & rsTemp("shelf") & """, ""shelf"", 2);'>" & Trim(rsTemp("shelf")) & "&nbsp</td>"
                strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='left' valign='middle' nowrap style='cursor:hand;' class='bodyTextTL' onMouseOver='this.style.color=""red"";' onMouseOut='this.style.color=""black"";' onClick='updateLocationsTable(""" & rsTemp("location") & """,""" & rsTemp("description") & """, ""description"", 101);'>" & Trim(rsTemp("description")) & "&nbsp</td>"
                strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='center' valign='middle' nowrap style='cursor:hand;' class='bodyTextTL' onMouseOver='this.style.color=""red"";' onMouseOut='this.style.color=""black"";' onClick='updateLocationsTable(""" & rsTemp("location") & """, """ & rsTemp("depth") & """, ""depth"", 2);'>" & Trim(rsTemp("depth")) & "&nbsp</td>"
                strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='left' valign='middle' nowrap style='cursor:hand;' class='bodyTextTL' onMouseOver='this.style.color=""red"";' onMouseOut='this.style.color=""black"";' onClick='updateLocationsTable(""" & rsTemp("location") & """, """ & rsTemp("status") & """, ""status"", 1);'>" & Trim(rsTemp("status")) & "&nbsp</td>"
                strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='left' valign='middle' nowrap style='cursor:hand;' class='bodyTextTL' onMouseOver='this.style.color=""red"";' onMouseOut='this.style.color=""black"";' onClick='updateLocationsTable(""" & rsTemp("location") & """, """ & rsTemp("class") & """, ""class"", 31);'>" & Trim(rsTemp("class")) & " <span style='font-size:10;'>(" & Trim(rsTemp("description2")) & ")</span>&nbsp</td>"
                strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='right' valign='middle' nowrap style='cursor:hand;' class='bodyTextTL' onMouseOver='this.style.color=""red"";' onMouseOut='this.style.color=""black"";' onClick='updateLocationsTable(""" & rsTemp("location") & """, """ & rsTemp("crossdock") & """, ""crossdock"", 2);'>" & Trim(rsTemp("crossdock")) & "&nbsp</td>"
                strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='right' valign='middle' nowrap class='bodyTextTL'>" & Trim(rsTemp("last_count")) & "&nbsp</td>"
                strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='right' valign='middle' nowrap style='cursor:hand;' class='bodyTextTL' onMouseOver='this.style.color=""red"";' onMouseOut='this.style.color=""black"";' onClick='updateLocationsTable(""" & rsTemp("location") & """,""" & rsTemp("cc_required") & """, ""cc_required"", 2);'>" & rsTemp("cc_required") & "&nbsp</td>"
                strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='center' valign='middle' nowrap style='cursor:hand;' class='bodyTextTL' onMouseOver='this.style.color=""red"";' onMouseOut='this.style.color=""black"";' onClick='changeLocationStatus(""" & rsTemp("location") & """, """ & rsTemp("active") & """);'>" & strActive & "&nbsp</td>"
                    strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='center' valign='center' nowrap class='bodyTextTLR'>"
                        'strTemp = strTemp & "<input type='checkbox' name='" & rsTemp("location") & "~" & rsTemp("shelf") & "' style='cursor:hand;' class='bodyText' onClick='buildPrintList();'></input>"
                        strTemp = strTemp & "<input type='checkbox' name='" & rsTemp("location") & "<~>" & rsTemp("shelf") & "' style='cursor:hand;' class='bodyText' onClick='buildPrintList();'></input>"
                    strTemp = strTemp & "</td>"
            strTemp = strTemp & "</tr>"
            rsTemp.MoveNext
        Loop

        strTemp = strTemp & "<tr>"
            strTemp = strTemp & "<td align='right' valign='middle' colspan='11' nowrap style='font-size: 10; font-weight: bold;' class='bodyTextT'>&nbsp</td>"
        strTemp = strTemp & "</tr>"

    End If
    rsTemp.Close

    strTemp = strTemp & "</table>"
    Response.Write(strTemp)
```

Comment: `name="123<~>1"` is invalid right there. It ought to be `name="123&lt;~&gt;1"`, and in actuality you should not use angle brackets in element names at all.

Comment: Ok awesome will do some playing around with the names then, Thank you! :D

Comment: Not sure if that was the problem, it's only the first thing that caught my eye.

Comment: My checkbox before its run looks like this `<input type='checkbox' name='" & rsTemp("location") & "<~>" & rsTemp("shelf") & "' style='cursor:hand;' class='bodyText' onClick='buildPrintList();'>`

Comment: @Tomalak I dont know what the &lt; and &gt; are for?

Comment: &lt = < and &gt = > ?

Comment: It *should* look like this: `<input type='checkbox' name='" & Server.HTMLEncode( rsTemp("location") & "<~>" & rsTemp("shelf") ) & "' style='cursor:hand;' class='bodyText' onClick='buildPrintList();'>`, but really, do it without the angle brackets, that's just asking for trouble. Also, it looks like your use case lends itself perfectly to jQuery, you would have a much easier time then re-implementing all the Ajax and document traversal/element selection stuff yourself.

Comment: That change (&lt; and &gt;) didn't affect anything because it would still show as <~> when it was ran...

Comment: Even just removing the brackets did not allow it to happen :(

Comment: Well, I think it's high time that you set up a proper sample consisting of your actual HTML source code (not the ASP stuff, but as the browser sees it) and all relevant JS code (not *everything*, but only those bits of that are concerned with selecting the data you want). Remove all Ajax stuff, for example, as it doesn't matter for the problem at hand. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Maybe all your input elements are being rendered with `name="activeonly"` OR maybe the variable initialization `frmMain = document.frmMain;` is not pointing to your form. Try `frmMain = document.getElementById( 'frmMain' );`, don't forgeting to put `id="frmMain"` at the form element.

Comment: No go on either of those changes :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dLa1gg5e/ without `document.getElementById`

http://jsfiddle.net/26s9o9p3/ with `document.getElementById`

Comment: That logic works just fine in jsfiddle... I don't get it.. Looks like I am going to have to edit my original question with the HTML and all....